# Fresh Ubuntu Install Won't Boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, ubuntu-minimal

I feel a little dumb for having to ask question to what will probably turn out to be a simple answer, but I have been pulling hairs over this for a few days. I am trying to set up an Ubuntu system for some things I want to try out at home. I have installed Linux on systems before and it has always been pretty strait forward for what I need, but this time I can't seem to get it to boot.

I was looking for a minimal system and came across this article: https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-a-minimal-ubuntu-on-old-laptop/

Seemed pretty straitforward, so I grabbed an old usb, prepared it and started the installation process. Everything went fine until I went to restart. The system would not boot. I figured I did something wrong, so I booted from the USB and magically I got into Ubuntu command line (I installed the desktop version, but for whatever reason it seemed to not have installed). I thought that was ok, but then realized the boot was happening from my USB which is not what I wanted, so I decided to try again.

This time I had read that sometimes choosing the default options installs the GRUB boot loader to the USB, so to specify the hard drive (/dev/sdb in my case). I tried with /dev/sdb as well as /dev/sdb1 and then I could still get my install prompt from the USB, but could not not anything to boot (not even the command line)

Another place I read that I need to set the boot flag on my new partition to ensure that everything can boot properly. So yet again I tried the install, this time partititioning the drive manually (still somewhat automatic through the installer) and set the boot flag on the primary partition.

Still no success. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am pretty much following the article above step for step except for setting the boot flag on my primary parition and specifying /dev/sdb for the GRUB boot loader.

My setup is a single hard drive that gets partitioned by the installer into two partitions (primary '/' 996GB and secondary 'swap' 4GB)

Comment: Well I found out something that at least lets me manually boot up, but doesn't work automatically yet. Apparently if I hold right shift after turning my pc on, the GRUB menu shows up and I can choose my Ubuntu installation. I guess that solves the question of booting now I just need to find a way to not have to stand there and hold shift every reboot.